# Accidentally removed /etc/pam.d/common-* files

Tags: 12.04, pam

I accidentally removed /etc/pam.d/common-* files on Ubuntu 12.04 through ssh. I have a backup of the files however, I am unable to use sudo nor log back in. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this question, as I have a system I borked messing with /etc/pam.d settings for samba domain login capabilities.  Anybody???